# Anti-delta function?

Tags: reference-request, fourier-transform, schwartz-distributions, generalized-functions

Did anyone ever consider a "function" or "distribution" $F(x)$ with the following property:
its integral $\int_a^b F(x)\,dx=0$ for any finite interval $(a,b)$ but $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)\,dx=1$? It definitely can be seen as a limit of smooth functions, and its Fourier transform will be a finction, equal to $1$ at $0$ and otherwise $0$.

I think such object for sure should be considered and named by someone.

Comment: For example, some kind of weak limit of $\chi_{[n,n+1]}$, characteristic functions of intervals? What is the goal?

Comment: you might take $F(x)=x^{-2}\delta(1/x)$.

Comment: I would say of $\chi_{[-n-1/2,-n]\cup [n,n+1/2]}$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker this is very interesting! Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker for instance, what's its Fourier transform?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I have tried bilateral Laplace transform on your function in Mathematica, but got 0...

Comment: @Anixx: What do you mean by "«function» or «distribution»"? Clearly there is no such function, nor there is such distribution, as long as $\int_a^b F(x) dx = 0$ implies $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x) \varphi(x) dx = 0$ for continuous, compactly supported $\varphi$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki possibly, some kind of generalized or hyper-function? Actually, the path that led me to this question is twofold: 1. When thinking on a theory of divergent integrals I sometimes encountered with desirable identity $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 0dx=1$ as a zeroth term is some series. 2. The zero-rank matrix is considered to have trace 0 and determinant 1 which corresponds in the functional space to values 0 everywhere but integral over domain equal to 1.

Comment: Anti-delta? be careful, they may arrest you.

Comment: @WlodAA who they?

Comment: @anixx - a sarcastic wordplay, I'd say...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms did not get it. Any clarification?

Comment: "Delta" is the name of a covid19-variant. And if you introduce something like an "Anti-delta"-concept someone might lose his/her humour and get very unfriendly... This why I meant it might be "a sarcastic wordplay"... (unfortunately jokes don't work when they must be explained...)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's quite a bit on this in Harold Jeffreys's unusual book *Theory of Probability*, in which such a function is one of the more prominent examples of “improper priors.” In [Robert, Chopin, and Rousseau – Harold Jeffreys's Theory of Probability Revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3173) we find this:

> For a 21st century reader, Jeffreys’s *Theory of Probability* is nonetheless puzzling for its lack of formalism, including its difficulties in handling improper priors, its reliance on intuition, its long debate about the nature of probability, and its repeated attempts at philosophical justifications. The title itself is misleading in that there is absolutely no exposition of the mathematical bases of probability theory in the sense of Billingsley (1986) or Feller (1970): “Theory of Inverse Probability” would have been more accurate. In other words, the style of the book appears to be both verbose and often vague in its mathematical foundations for a modern reader.

Consider the upper half-plane $\{(m,s): -\infty<m<+\infty,\, 0<s<+\infty\}$ with the measure $dm\,ds/s.$ Pretend that when multiplied by some infinitely small constant (“constant” = not depending on $m$ or $s$) this becomes a probability measure on the upper half-plane. Now suppose that the conditional probability distribution of $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ given $m$ and $s$ is that they are independent and normally distributed with expected value $m$ and variance $s$ (variance, not standard deviation). What then is the conditional distribution of $(m,s)$ given $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$? It is a perfectly ordinary probability distribution. Jeffreys proposes that that is the conditional probability distribution of the expectation and variance of a population from which $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ is a random sample, when one has no other information about their values than what one gets from that sample.

Another example is the measure $c\,dp/\bigl(p(1-p)\bigr)$ whose integral over $(0,1)$ is $1$. Suppose $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ are conditionally independent given $p$ and $\Pr(X_k=1\mid p) = p$ and $\Pr(X_k=0\mid p)=1-p$ for $k=1,\dotsc,n$. Then the conditional distribution of $p$ given $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ is $\text{constant}\times p^{X_1+\dotsb+X_n-1}(1-p)^{n-(X_1+\dotsb+X_n)-1} \, dp,$ which is a perfectly ordinary probability distribution except when $X_1+\dotsb+X_n\in\{0,n\}$.

I think Jeffreys's doctorate was in mathematics, and he was a professor of astronomy for some time, and spent a lot of time on seismology and earth sciences, and in the '50s claimed to be able to tell the difference between seismic waves resulting from nuclear tests and those from earthquakes when the U.S. government was denying that that could be done.

The physicist Edwin Jaynes defended improper priors in a number of his writings.

Comment: Good! Now I know the name of this class of things.

Comment: Note that an improper prior can satisfy your given properties, but it is far from unique. Priors have more structure, e.g. you can compute the ratio of $\int_a^b F(x) dx$ for different intervals. If you want an object determined by its Fourier transform, you should look at measures on the compactification of $\mathbb{R}$, as explained in another answer.

Comment: The integral of 1/(p(1-p)) over (0, 1) is undefined, not 1.

Comment: @user76284 $$ \int\limits_{(0,1)} \frac{dp}{p(1-p)} = +\infty \ne 1 = \int\limits_{(0,1)} \frac{c\,dp}{p(1-p)}. $$ But what is the nature of this mysterious infinitely small quantity called $c\text{?}$ I don't know and probably nobody does, but this idea is sometimes used in statistics and in fact taught in some statistics courses in which the students are not majoring in mathematics or statistics, so it has some currency in the community.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Can you express the RHS as some kind of formal limit?

Comment: @user76284 : Probably not, but maybe somebody can. $\qquad$

Comment: Thinking about such things as the value of the supposed infinitely small quantity $c$ gets as little attention as thinking about the value and the nature of the infinitely large quantity that is the value at zero of $3.2$ times Dirac's delta function. Suppose you have a family of probability distributions of some random variable $X,$ and the parameter is $\mu,$ then $L(m) = \Pr(X=x\mid \mu=m)$ and $\mu$ itself has a prior probability distribution $f(m)\,dm.$ Then the posterior probability distribution of $\mu,$ i.e. the conditional distribution given that $X=x,$ is$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\, \text{constant} \times L(m)\times f(m)\,dm,$ and “constant” means not depending on $m$ (so it may depend on $x$, and typically does). That “constant” is the reciprocal of the marginal (or “unconditional,” i.e. not conditioned on $\mu$) probability of the event $X=x,$ or else it is the value of the _marginal_ probability density of $X$ at $x.$ And sometimes naive persons will try to compute that probability by integrating against $f(m)\,dm,$ thinking that they need it in order to find the posterior distribution. But usually it's immensely simpler just to$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$use what is already known about the particular parametrized family of distributions in which the posterior distribution is found, and you find that the integral is a simpler integral that you already did before. And that is a reason when the nature of $\text{“}c\text{”}$ deserves little attention if you're actually making practical use of improper priors.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ah, I see, but then this divergent integral is equal to $2\int_0^1 \frac1x dx$. Which in turn is equal to twice the harmonic series, whose regularized value is $\gamma$... What's the problem if in statistics they use a value reciprocal to a divergent integral?...

Answer (score 28):

Let $\beta\mathbb{R}$ be the Stone-Čech compactification of $\mathbb{R}$: any bounded continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ extends uniquely to a (necessarily bounded) continuous function $f^\beta$ on $\beta\mathbb{R}$.  Now consider a Radon probability measure $\mu$ on $\beta\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ (which might simply be the Dirac measure concentrated on a point of $\beta\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R}$).  Then integrating $f^\beta$ against $\mu$ gives a kind of “integral” of $f$ which has the properties you want: it is independent of the values of $f$ on any finite interval, and is equal to the limit of $f$ at infinity if such exists: so if you see $f$ as test functions (or restrict to some space of test functions that includes at least the bounded continuous functions) and see this integral as $\int f F$ for some generalized function $F$ (defined through its integral of test functions, like distributions), you have the properties you asked for.  But it is, obviously, very far from unique.

The notion of a [Banach limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit) is very closely related to what I just said (but for the natural numbers instead of the reals).

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use the Stone-Čech compactification?

Comment: @w123: We need the Stone-Čech compactification to guarantee that a bounded continuous function always extends to a continuous function on the compactification.

Answer (score 10):

To elaborate on the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415007/anti-delta-function#comment1064294_415007), I would suggest to take $F(x)=x^{-2}\delta(1/x)$. Let me check for the representation
$\delta_{\epsilon}(x)=(2\pi\epsilon)^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/2\epsilon}$,
and $F_\epsilon(x)=x^{-2}\delta_\epsilon(1/x)$. Then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_\epsilon(x)dx=1$, for any $\epsilon$, while $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_a^b F_\epsilon(x)\,dx=0$. It seems to have the desired properties.

Comment: Did you use any known properties when deriving this? For instance, identities for $\delta(1/x)$ or Laplace transform?

Comment: Well, I was wondering what thinking path led you to this development? Also, why it is assumed that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_\epsilon(x)=1$ is continuous at $\epsilon=0$? Also, does $\delta_{\epsilon}(x)$ mean delta function with support at $\epsilon$?

Comment: just dimensional analysis, $F(x)dx$ should be dimensionless, so if you wish to map 0 onto $\infty$ by taking $F(x)\propto\delta(1/x)$ you need a factor $1/x^2$; $\delta_\epsilon(x)$ is a mollified delta function [$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\delta_\epsilon(x)=\delta(x)$].

Comment: Very interesting, but still I do not understand :-) You said, $F(x)$ is dimensionless. Is it similar to an empty matrix https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913141/is-the-0-times-0-matrix-zero-times-zero-matrix-a-well-defined-concept/2229223?noredirect=1#comment9128968_2229223 ?

Comment: As others state that $F(x)$ cannot be a distribution, what $1/x^2 \delta(1/x)$ from your answer supposed to be? A hyperfunction? Or some formal expression?

Comment: I think this is basically what [Gro-Tsen wrote](https://mathoverflow.net/a/415013/3948), except instead of Stone-Čech you take the one-point compactification and require your functions to have a limit at $\infty$.

Comment: So, using this variant of delta function https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627326/squarable-delta-function/4628238?noredirect=1#comment9763947_4628238 it would be $\overline{\delta}(1/x)$.

Answer (score 9):

This is more a long comment following the ones of [Mateusz Kwasnicki](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415007/anti-delta-function#comment1064301_415007) and [Anixx](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415007/anti-delta-function#comment1064306_415007) and the nice answers given by Michael Hardy, Gro-Tsen, et al.
As stated by Mateusz, such a mathematical objiect cannot be a function nor a distribution: indeed in this last case, without a compactification of the real line (as suggested by [Gro-Tsen'asnswer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/415013/113756)), there's no $\varphi\in C_0^\infty$ whose support is compact and includes the point at infinity, so the space of functionals on function spaces made of this functions is necessarily empty. However, this limitation is not inherited by hyperfunctions: there exist hyperfunctions, notably Fourier hyperfunctions, "supported" (it is better to say "carried", since the support of a distribution and the carrier of a hyperfunction are not exactly the same) at $x=+\infty$. The first explicit example of such kind of generalized functions was constructed by Morimoto and Yoshino [2], and was lated simplified and extended by Akira Kaneko in [1] (who also deals with the higher dimensional case). The method (as explained by Kaneko [1] pp. 99-100) consists in choosing a defining function for the sought for hyperfunction which grows very fast on the real axis, for example $e^{e^{z^2}}=\exp\big(e^{z^2}\big)$, and a path $\gamma$ to $+\infty$ along which it rapidly decreases: then the holomorphic function $F(z)$ defined as
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\dmu}{\operatorname{d}\!}
F(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_\gamma \frac{\exp\big(e^{\zeta^2}\big)}{\zeta-z} \dmu\zeta
$$
is such that its "boundary value" (i.e. the defined hyperfunction) $f(x) =F(x+i0)-F(x-i0)$ is $0$ for all finite $x\in\Bbb R$, as it can be proved by deforming the integration path and using the standard Cauchy integral theorem. But nevertheless it is
$$
F(x)= \exp\big(e^{x^2}\big) + \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_\gamma \frac{\exp\big(e^{\zeta^2}\big)}{\zeta -x} \dmu\zeta
$$
thus the "boundary value" of $F$ produces a non trivial Fourier hyperfunction carried at $+\infty$.

**Bibliography**

[1] Akira Kaneko, "[Explicit construction of Fourier hyperfunctions supported at infinity](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812776594_0007)" (English), Kawai, Takahiro (ed.) et al., *Microlocal analysis and complex Fourier analysis*, River Edge, NJ: World Scientific Publishers, ISBN 981-238-161-9/hbk, pp. 99-114 (2002), [MR2068531](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR2068531), [Zbl 1046.46031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1046.46031).

[2] Mitsuo Morimoto, Kunio Yoshino, "[Some examples of analytic functionals with carrier at the infinity](https://doi.org/10.3792/pjaa.56.357)" (English),Proceedings of the Japan Academy, Series A 56, 357-361 (1980), [MR0596004](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0596004),  [Zbl 0471.46024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0471.46024).

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that, insofar as a "generalized distribution" like your $F$ exists in some sense, there would have to be a continuum of them, corresponding to different possible values $0 ≤ c ≤ 1$ of the integral $c = \int_{-\infty}^0 F_c(x)\ {\rm d}x$ over the left half line.*

In some sense, every such $F_c$ is indeed a generalized probability distribution.  In particular, every probability distribution $g$ over the real line is uniquely defined by its [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (CDF), i.e. the unique function $G$ such that $\int_a^b g(x)\ {\rm d}x = G(b) - G(a)$.

Normally we insist that if $G$ is a CDF over $\mathbb R$ it must satisfy $\lim_{x \to -\infty}G(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty}G(x) = 1$, which essentially amounts to insisting that all of the probability mass of the corresponding distribution $g$ can be found somewhere along the real line (or, more precisely, that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a bounded interval $[a,b] \in \mathbb R$ such that $\int_a^b g(x)\ {\rm d}x ≥ 1 - \epsilon$).

However, if we relax that restriction, then the "distribution" $F_c$ has a well defined and unique CDF — which is merely the constant $c$.  And it seems to me that a lot of the theory of probability distributions should indeed generalize decently well to such "improper" distributions with non-zero probability mass at (positive and/or negative) infinity.**

I'm not, unfortunately, personally familiar with any existing literature on such generalized probability distributions and their uses.  But I'd be very surprised if *no-one* had studied these things at some point.

---

<sup>*) Of course even more possibilities exist if we allow the integral of $F_c$ to be negative over some (unbounded) intervals, in which case $c$ could be any real number.  But I suspect that this is generalizing a bit too far, since non-negativity of the integral is a natural and useful property of probability distributions.  And if we *do* wish to go beyond those and consider (generalizations of) arbitrary signed measures, then I see no good reason to keep the restriction $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x)\ {\rm d}x = 1$ either.</sup>

<sup>**) In fact, I guess one could simply treat these things as distributions over the [extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).  Which I suppose may be why nobody's bothered to study them much, since looked at like that, the whole concept is really rather trivial.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

We can define your "anti-delta function" as an unusual **type of distribution**.

First, describe $F$ in terms of the integral $\langle F,\varphi\rangle:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x)\,\varphi(x)\,dx$ for some test function $\varphi$.
If I understand you correctly, you want this to be $\langle F,\varphi\rangle=\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\frac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^{a}\varphi(x)\,dx$, which is a linear functional of $\varphi$.

Distributions are defined as *continuous*/*bounded* linear functionals on a given space of test functions.
There are various different [spaces of distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_of_test_functions_and_distributions#Spaces_of_distributions), depending on the domain of $\varphi$ used in their definition. The "anti-delta function" is not a distribution in the normal sense, because on the usual domains like $C_{c}^\infty$ or $C^\infty$ our functional $\langle F,\,\cdot\,\rangle$ is either identically zero, ill-defined or unbounded. To make $F$ a distribution, we need to choose another space of test functions $\varphi$, such that the limit $\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}\tfrac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^{a}\varphi(x)\,dx$ is well-defined and continuous in $\varphi$.

A way to construct viable function spaces and to simplify $\langle F, \varphi\rangle$ is to extend the domain of $\varphi$ to a compactification of $\mathbb{R}$.
Possible test functions would include continuous functions on the one-point compactification $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$, where $\langle F,\varphi\rangle=\varphi(\infty)$ (making it a "delta function at infinity").

Some of the other answers can be seen as variants of this: Using CDFs is equivalent to considering test functions $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}\to \mathbb{R}$ on the two-point compactification, where $\langle F,\varphi\rangle = c\,\varphi(-\infty)+(1-c)\,\varphi(\infty)$. Hyperfunctions are generalized distributions with holomorphic test functions.